# In the Sin of the Golden Calf, What was Forgiven?

Tags: golden-calf-egel, kaparah-atonement

Rashi (Shemot 32:34) quotes the Talmud (Sanhedrin 102a) and says "וְאֵין פֻּרְעָנוּת בָּאָה עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁאֵין בָּהּ קְצָת מִפִּרְעוֹן עֲוֹן הָעֵגֶל - *Indeed no punishment ever comes upon Israel in which there is not part payment for the sin of the golden calf."*

If that is the case, and there is still a "debt" that is due, what was accomplished when it says, וַיֹּאמֶר ה' סָלַחְתִּי כִּדְבָרֶךָ - *And the L-rd said, "I have forgiven them in accordance with your word.* (Bamidbar 14:20) ???

Is it because the forgiveness was based on the initial request where it says, "פֹּקֵד עֲוֹן אָבוֹת עַל־בָּנִים עַל־שִׁלֵּשִׁים וְעַל־רִבֵּעִים - *Who visits the iniquities of parents on children, even to the third and fourth generations.'*

If there is always a residual effect of this sin, what was forgiven?

Comment: To administer the punishment in a manner that wouldn't wipe them out wholesale which is apparently what the sin should have resulted in

Comment: The kli yakar says what @Nahum is saying מיד וינחם ה' על הרעה אשר דבר לעשות לעמו. היינו מה שדבר לעשות לכלותם לגמרי, אבל מ"מ חשב ליסרם בשבט פשעם כמ"ש וביום פקדי ופקדתי עליהם את חטאתם, להפרע מהם מעט מעט
https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Exodus.32.11.2?lang=bi

Comment: Wasn't Bamidbar 14:20 said regarding the Sin of the Spies (Or [the call to return to Egypt](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.14.4?lang=bi&lang2=he), that followed)?

Comment: Every sin has a residual effect at some level. There's always a higher level of repentance and a higher level of forgiveness: https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/tanya.asp?tdate=2/22/2024